# JQuery - Data from .data() is lost

Tags: jquery

I have this code in a function that creates an anchor, stores data and appends it to a div element

```
var x = $("<a class='randomclass'></a>");
x.data('foo', 'bar');
console.log(x.data());
...
$("<div></div>").append(
    x
);
...
```

Now when I try to have an event handler that gets that data back, it shows that its undefined. I have tried different ways to access element but they all return no data

```
$("body").on("click", "a.randomclass", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log( $(event.target).data('foo') );
   console.log( $(event.currentTarget).data('foo') );
   console.log( $(this).data('foo') );
});
```

Any reason why this is so?

EDIT: Fixed typo.

Comment: Can't you just do `$(this).data("foo")`?

Comment: @jSang He does it in the last line.

Comment: Where the element `$("<div></div>")` goes then?

Comment: Are you sure that the element is getting attached to the DOM rather than just a fragment?

Comment: This seems to be working just fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/JjqCF/ I'm assuming you appended that div somewhere on the page, otherwise what where you clicking ?

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/PZcHr/1/

Comment: As I said on the answer below, make sure you are appending the div to the document, the code seems to be OK

Comment: Hmmm don't know if this information helps but the anchor is inserted inside a google map v3 marker dialog via the infoWindowContent attribute https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en#Markers

Comment: And suddenly the question is something else entirely, like "how to attach event handler to anchor in Gmaps" ?

Comment: @adeneo I don't think it changes anything. The element can still be accessed normally using JQuery without having to resort to any Gmaps specific code. I mentioned the Gmaps thing because I thought that it might be a factor in the element losing the data. But I doubt it.

Comment: So if console logging a random string it shows up when clicking inside the infowindow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I think I found the answer guys.

The problem is that I got the markup of the element using .html() and passed it to a function.

I guess that means that any data of that element is lost since .html() just gets the string representation of that element.

Comment: Please be more concise and paste the real code when you ask your following question, people trying to help you won't waste their time.

Comment: Saved my rear on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work for me. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/XWDeE/)

```
var x = $("<a class='randomclass'>test link</a>");
x.data('foo', 'bar');
console.log(x.data());

$("body").append(x);

$("body").on("click", "a.randomclass", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).data());
});​
```

Comment: +1, it seems that the problem he is not appending the div to the document

Comment: Hmmm don't know if this information helps but the anchor is inserted inside a google map v3 marker dialog via the infoWindowContent attribute https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en#Markers